# Choosing language

Tags: html, css, django, user-interface

Choosing language I see http://github.com/ and OpenBSD.org got 2 examples how to. Github has a dropdown and openbsd.org just links. Which kind of UI for this use case could you recommend?
I now take the parameter hl=el for instance for greek which switches i18n internals to greek or other language and present available languages like this

```
{% get_current_language as LANGUAGE_CODE %}&nbsp;<b>{{ LANGUAGE_CODE }}</b>{% get_available_languages as LANGUAGES %}{% for LANGUAGE in LANGUAGES %}{% ifnotequal LANGUAGE_CODE LANGUAGE.0 %}&nbsp;<a href='?hl={{ LANGUAGE.0 }}'>{{ LANGUAGE.0 }}</a>{% endifnotequal %}{% endfor %}
```

It's possible to think other parameter handling than for instance http get hl=el for a greek ui and there is no obvious standard. Most sites seem to use a dropdown where a combined dropdown with most common languages directly by links also look feasible option. I hope you can comment or recommend these alternatives.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [default l10n middleware](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/i18n/deployment/#how-django-discovers-language-preference) looks for a session variable or cookie with the name `django_language`.

Comment: By default I set this variable to http accept language header. Do you agree that's a good idea? It's possible to imagine a Greek user using a computer in London that has english http accept header needing a user defined variable to know to display in greek. I now do it with get parameter hl=el also conceivable as locale=el

Comment: If you only look at that header then you don't need to set the variable; like the documentation says, it looks at that first.

Comment: Thanks for the info. So I understand that django will make the choice by default when i18n is loaded in the templates.